# open closed principle in functional programming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, software-design

I have been reading some articles about the open-closed principle and all seem to be related to OOP.

Is there a way to do open-closed principle in functional programming using Node.JS for example?

Comment: You can declare classes in Javascript, abstracts and inherit from them, in what use case are you thinking of applying this principle?

Comment: see this - https://dev.to/carstenbehrens/solid-open-closed-principle-in-javascript-2a1g

Comment: @PietroNadalini use case: Example use-case would be a different type of products

Add Physical products to Cart.
Extend the functionality to add Gift-Card to Cart.
Extend the functionality to add Downloadable Music to Cart

Comment: If, as the OP says *"open-closed principle ... seem to be related to OOP"*, why then does the OP think it should not be possible to be achieved with node.js ? On the other hand, since the OP choose as title *"open closed principle in functional programming"*, what does the OP make believe that JavaScript is a functional programming language. Which leads to another question, does the OP actually know the core features of JS?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I know OOP is possible in JS (Eg: Typescript) - I am asking how we can do this in functional programming in JS.

Comment: *"I am asking how we can do this in functional programming in JS"* ok, then for JS the Q. could be refined to ... ***Is it possible to entirely cover the "open closed principle" in JavaScript based on functions and closures only?*** Good. Know I have something to think and research about ... mainly on what "open closed" actually does mean/cover especially in the context of JS.

Comment: The open/closed principle is about being able to extend functionality without modifying core code.  Most OOP systems provide an extension mechanism as part of the design of the OOP (Javascript classes and inheritance, for example) and when used appropriately extension is easy.  Functional programming does not by itself define such an extension mechanism, but nothing is stopping you from making your own extension mechanism - it would just be something you have to design and implement yourself using your own functional programming code.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to achieve this principle, for example if you create classes, you can inherit the functions and then extend its functionality. For example:

```
class NumberConverter {
  isNumber(number) {
    return true;
  }

  convertBase(number, fromBase, toBase) {
    return parseInt(number, fromBase).toString(toBase);
  }
}

class DecimalToBinary extends NumberConverter {
  isDecimalNumber(number) {
    return true;
  }

  dec2bin(number) {
    return this.convertBase(number, 10, 2);
  }
}
```

You can see how you can extend the `convertBase` and extend its functionality. You can extend from multiple classes just adding a comma after each class like `extends Products, Music`.

But if you want to create another kind of approach, you can do composition instead of inheritance, meaning that with the previous example, you can make a new class like so:

```
class Calculator {
  properties;
  numberConverter;

  setDecimalConverter(numberConverter) {
    this.numberConverter = numberConverter;
  }

  convertDec2bin(number) {
    return this.numberConverter.convertBase(number, 10, 2);
  }
}
```

So then you can use the new class `Calculator` like this:

```
const calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.numberConverter = new NumberConverter(); // If you don't want to do this, you would have to add the NumberConverter in the Calculator constructor
calculator.convertDec2bin(5);
```

And all of this functionality can be done as a function. (Although it might not be exactly an open-closed principle, I think it still solves your use case). You can use it like this:

```
const Calculator = function(NumberConverter) {
  const numberConverter = NumberConverter;

  return {
    convertDec2bin(number) {
      return numberConverter.convertBase(number, 10, 2);
    }
  }  
}

const calculator = Calculator(NumberConverter());
calculator.convertDec2bin(5)
```

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back ... The last approach shows the unique *object-functional* style of how one does achieve such tasks in class free JS.

Answer (score 1):

**Sure**, indeed FP is all about reusing functions to build new ones.

For example:

You can declare a function `add :: Number -> Number -> Number`

```
const add = (x) => (y) => x + y
```

And then use `add` to build another function like `mult :: Number -> Number -> Number`

```
const mult = (x) => (y) => y === 0 ? 0 : add(x)(mult(x)(y - 1))
```

Each function could be considered atomic, as there's no need to do further changes. So, by this way you don't modify previous functions, you re-use them to form new ones.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following. Are you be able to provide a quick example like this: Example use-case would be a different type of products: Add Physical products to Cart. Extend the functionality to add Gift-Card to Cart. Extend the functionality to add Downloadable Music to Cart

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back ... The mentioned use case shows a very object centric view. Since JS is a multi-paradigmatic language the requirements have to be very clear whether on top of functions/closures are also objects being allowed to be passed around, and more importantly, whether they are allowed to be passed as references, thus being allowed to be mutated. If not, then the OP is looking for something like an approach based on pure functional programming where I strongly doubt something like the OP describes is achievable at all.

Comment: I would love to see more examples. Based on my nascent knowledge of FP, I suspect @forensor is onto something with composition. But I too am having trouble right now seeing an approach to composition that abides by the open-close principle.